# How can I keep user account settings across multiple computers?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, user-profiles, network-drive, roaming-profiles

I work with a team of around 15 people, all on different shifts. There are 5 different computers running Windows 10 where we work, and we use different machines from shift to shift, depending on which ones are unoccupied when we start our shifts.

This leads to lots of annoyances when we change account settings on one machine, but they obviously don't apply to our accounts on the other 4 machines. We use credentials on our school's domain to sign in, but user profile folders are created on each machine locally when we log in for the first time.

Is there a way to have all of our profile folders on a network drive, or just on one of the machines, so we don't have to make every change 5 times?

I've read about roaming profiles, but I can't find many specific guides to setting these up, and I can't find any guides that are specific to Windows 10. Does Windows 10 still support roaming profiles? How do we go about setting them up?

Is there a better alternative that we could use?

Comment: This evolves your IT Administrator setting up roaming profiles.  You could do it manually if you wanted by using the network share.

Comment: We are all administrators on these computers, and have permission to image the machines or install whatever we need. Could you elaborate?

Comment: There can be used 2 techniques in this case: 1. Roaming profiles, 2 Redirected folders. Redirected folders is what you're looking for. It can redirect a users profile to a network path. Do note that when you redirect the My Documents folder to a network share, some programs may not want to install anymore, such as adobe reader. For either to work you do need a server with domain controller though.

Comment: roaming profiles require a domain server.  Its not clear if that is the case, being a local administrator, isn't enough

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Could either of you please expand your comments into answers?